# Getting address and coordinates from google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I want to add a google map in my website and letting my users pick a their location by clicking on the map in order to pass the address and coordinates to me (to store in my DB).

Does google provide this functionality? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pick their location from the map'? Would this be clicking on a marker or writing out the address.

Comment: I mean by clicking on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, it's called [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

edited:

You have to get the coordinates from the click first - add an event listener to the map for a 'click' event to call a function(event). Inside the function, you can access location by event.latLng. And from there, you can use the reverse-geocoding from the link above.

Comment: Geocoding is getting coordinates from address or vice versa. I want the option to get the address by clicking on the map.

Comment: Then you have to get the coordinates from the click first.

Comment: Add an event listener to the map for a 'click' event to call a function(event). Inside the function, you can access location by event.latLng. And from there, you can use the reverse-geocoding.